# How to execute php file from magento admin in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, controllers, script, file

I have created a php file on root folder of magento in Magento 2 and hit a controller on that file.
That process is done and i have tested it it running on terminal.

How would i run that script from magento backend on click a button is it possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can do this but you can change your way to do this.

Comment: How to proceed will you please tell me @DhirenVasoya

Comment: Why you not put that controller code into your button action?

Comment: In that controller code i have create product from txt file so it is very large file so it would be stuck after some time thats why i have to do this with php script.@DhirenVasoya

Comment: @Prits Create a queue type cron job that runs every minute and runs the task in the background, but only if the controller has added it to the "queue"